# How to formulate requests for these endpoints

Tags: http, go

I cannot figure out how to make the requests for "access", "clock" and "audit" with the required parameters. Could you give me some guidance on how to make these requests?

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/subtle"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const secret = "galumphing"

// Required parameters for the request
type params struct {
    Act       string
    Nonce     string
    Signature string
    Timeout   int64
    Offset    int
}

var (
    auditLock sync.Mutex
    auditBase int
    auditLog  []string
)

var (
    seenLock sync.Mutex
    seenMap  = map[string]bool{}
)

var (
    clockAsk  = make(chan bool)
    clockTime = make(chan int64, 1)
)

func main() {
    // Endpoints available
    http.HandleFunc("/903/access", handleAccess)
    http.HandleFunc("/903/clock", handleClock)
    http.HandleFunc("/903/audit", handleAudit)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(os.Args[1], nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func checkCapacity(w http.ResponseWriter) (ok bool) {
    auditLock.Lock()
    defer auditLock.Unlock()

    if len(auditLog) > 10 {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusServiceUnavailable)
        return
    }

    ok = true
    return
}

func audit(r *http.Request, params params, ok bool) {
    auditLock.Lock()
    defer auditLock.Unlock()

    auditLog = append(auditLog, fmt.Sprintf("%v %q %q", ok, r.URL.Path, params.Act))
}

func parse(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (params params, ok bool) {
    defer func() {
        if !ok {
            audit(r, params, false)
        }
    }()

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600")

    if r.Method != "POST" {
        w.Header().Set("Allow", "POST, OPTIONS")
        if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        } else {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        }
        return
    }

    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&params)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        log.Printf("%s: %v", r.URL.Path, err)
        return
    }

    h := sha256.New()
    fmt.Fprintf(h, "%s\r\n%s\r\n%s\r\n%s", r.URL.Path, params.Act, params.Nonce, secret)
    sig := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
    if subtle.ConstantTimeCompare([]byte(sig), []byte(params.Signature)) != 1 {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }

    seenLock.Lock()
    seen := seenMap[params.Signature]
    if !seen {
        seenMap[params.Signature] = true
    }
    seenLock.Unlock()
    if seen {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }

    ok = true
    return
}

func handleAccess(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if !checkCapacity(w) {
        return
    }

    params, ok := parse(w, r)
    if !ok {
        return
    }

    switch params.Act {
    case "begin":
        if params.Timeout < 0 || params.Timeout > 250000 {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            audit(r, params, false)
            return
        }

        timer := time.NewTimer(time.Duration(params.Timeout) * time.Microsecond)

        select {
        case clockAsk <- true: // https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
            audit(r, params, true)

        case <-timer.C:
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusConflict)
            audit(r, params, false)
            return
        }

        go func() {
            <-timer.C

            select {
            case <-clockTime:
            default:
            }
        }()

    case "end":
        if params.Timeout < 0 {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            audit(r, params, false)
            return
        }

        timer := time.NewTimer(time.Duration(params.Timeout) * time.Microsecond)

        select {
        case value := <-clockTime: // https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            fmt.Fprintln(w, value)
            audit(r, params, true)

        case <-timer.C:
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusConflict)
            audit(r, params, false)
        }

    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        audit(r, params, false)
    }
}

func handleClock(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if !checkCapacity(w) {
        return
    }

    params, ok := parse(w, r)
    if !ok {
        return
    }

    switch params.Act {
    case "observe":
        if params.Timeout != 0 {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            audit(r, params, false)
            return
        }

        select {
        case <-clockAsk: // https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator
            select {
            case clockTime <- time.Now().Unix(): // https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements
            default:
            }

        default:
        }

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
        audit(r, params, true)

    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        audit(r, params, false)
    }
}

func handleAudit(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params, ok := parse(w, r)
    if !ok {
        return
    }

    ok = false

    func() {
        auditLock.Lock()
        defer auditLock.Unlock()

        switch params.Act {
        case "":
            if params.Offset != 0 {
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
                return
            }

            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            fmt.Fprintln(w, auditBase)

        case "burble":
            if params.Offset < auditBase || params.Offset > auditBase+len(auditLog) {
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
                return
            }

            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

            for i := params.Offset - auditBase; i < len(auditLog); i++ {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d %s\n", auditBase+i, auditLog[i])
            }

        case "chortle":
            if params.Offset > auditBase+len(auditLog) {
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
                return
            }

            if params.Offset > auditBase {
                auditLog = auditLog[params.Offset-auditBase:] // https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions
                auditBase = params.Offset
            }

            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)

        default:
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        ok = true
    }()

    audit(r, params, ok)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this. You can either use a tool like Postman, or simply just use `curl` from the command line to send a post request to your endpoint. Here is the curl command that I used to hit the endpoint (I am using port 8080 for my testing), the bit after the `-d` flag is the request body:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/903/access -d '{"Act": "act", "Nonce": "nonce", "Signature": "signature", "TimeOut": 64, "Offset": 0}'`

I did modify the code to cut out most of the logic. This request just shows an example of how the current code can parse the request body. If you are interested more in how some of the other logic works in the handler functions, let me know and I can edit my response. Here is the code that I used for my testing:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

// Required parameters for the request
type params struct {
    Act       string
    Nonce     string
    Signature string
    Timeout   int64
    Offset    int
}

func main() {
    // Endpoints available
    http.HandleFunc("/903/access", handleAccess)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(os.Args[1], nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func parse(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (params params, ok bool) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600")

    if r.Method != "POST" {
        w.Header().Set("Allow", "POST, OPTIONS")
        if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        } else {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        }
        return
    }

    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&params)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        log.Printf("%s: %v", r.URL.Path, err)
        return
    }

    return
}

func handleAccess(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params, _ := parse(w, r)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", params)
}
```

Here is the output that I received when all is said and done:

`{Act:act Nonce:nonce Signature:signature Timeout:64 Offset:0}`